# Get marker coordinates from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I added google map to my website and now what i want to do is when a person marks a marker on the map i need the coordinates of the marker to be set in 2 labels lat and lng
here's what i did so far

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(33.9000, 35.5333);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: haightAshbury,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }

    // Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
    function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
        });
        var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and for the Labels :

```
<div id="panel">
    <label id="lat"><script>document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML=lat;</script></label>
    <label id="lng"><script>document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML=lng;</script></label>
</div>
```

sorry in advance but a beginner....thank you

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a nifty trick with the script tag in between label tags. Scripts are evaluated on page load and so the position of your script inside the label will not magically update your label tags like that.

Instead, try to add that functionality inside `addMarker()` so it does what it's name "add a marker" intents to do (or what do you want it to do?).

```
function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        }),
        lat = document.getElementById('lat'),
        lng = document.getElementById('lng');

    lat.innerHTML = location.lat();
    lng.innerHTML = location.lng();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery and assign lat lng  to label with the help of `.html()` ,

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VC88F/)